# Arc length between configurations in the "mass distance"

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, mass, mathematics, distance

In classical Lagrangian mechanics, the mass $M$ is a Riemannian metric on the configuration space $Q$.
Does the "arc length" of a path $\gamma : [0, 1] \to Q$,
$$
\int_0^1 {\lVert{\gamma'(t)}\rVert}_{M}\,dt
$$

have a physical meaning?

When there's just one particle, this arc length is just the distance that the particle travels, multiplied by the square root of the particle's mass.